# By design, why isn't there a single parameter ctor for int?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace FirstApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(params string[] args)
        {
            int x = new int();
            x = 12;
            //int y = new int(12);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

By design, why isn't there a single parameter ctor for `int` such that `x` can be set to 12 without having to be set to 0 first?

Comment: What would be the point of having it?

Comment: @harold: for the sake of completeness. Will its existance impact the performance?

Comment: What purpose would a constructor on an integer be?

Comment: @Forgiver - Besides being a horrible idea there would be no measureable performance impact.

Comment: I don't think it's ever occured to me to even try and use a constructor for an int

Comment: @Ramhound: Actually, there probably would be (without special case optimization). See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason lies in the CLR itself. The CLR does not treat `Int32` as any ordinary struct. It has a special type for storing `int`, which is not a CLR object. This means that it does not need a contructor, just like an `int` in C does not have a constructor.

Also, the CLR handling of struct default contructors is to set all fields to their default value. For int this is 0. `new int()` does seem to be a special case, simply being an 'alias' for 0, eliminating any constructor altogether.

Plus, this is just plain better.

```
int x = 12;
```

Comment: +1 only answer which actually answers the OP's question.

Comment: Does this explain `Int16` and `Int64` or is this special CLR handling purely for `Int32`?

Comment: @Adam: The CLR handles Int16 and Int64 similarly.

Comment: @KendallFrey Do you have any links / sources for this?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: It comes from my experience with MSIL, but I can try to find a link.

Comment: @KendallFrey Or some sample code to demonstrate the issue, I'm just curious - sounds interesting. So at the end of the day `int i = 0;` compiles into different IL than `int i = new int();`? As in, specifically different because it is optimized.

Comment: Good question. The default constructor seems to have been implemented by the CLR to simply return 0. Let me test this.

Comment: Yes, both statements generate `ldc.i4.0 stloc.<X>`. That is with optimizations disabled.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I don't think there is documentation on the CLR, because it is probably 'subject to change'. But I did find this: http://munro.humber.ca/~kheiri/cpan/cpan701/lecture1/pdfs/CLR.pdf

Comment: @KendallFrey That document refers to a 'native int', this is a completely seperate entity to the `int` struct in C#.

Comment: @rich.okelly: Yes. It also talks about int32 and similar types, which are the ones used for an Int32 and similar.

Comment: @KendallFrey If they answer is they **cannot** create constructors, what is stopping them? Or is the answer that a constructor is worthless and hence they didn't need to implement any?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: It is very similar to an int in C. There is no functionality (including constructors). It is just several bytes of memory. Non-primitive structs include a type definition, which allows them to include properties, methods, and constructors.

Comment: @KendallFrey I'm not sure how this applies to C# as the `Int32` struct, of which `int` is an alias, has members other than those defined on `object`. So I see no reason why it couldn't have constructors (but plenty of reasons why it doesn't).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: True. Good point. In this case it seems like the Int32 type definition is sort of a wrapper for int32. It even has an int32 field, called m_value.

Comment: Regardless of what MSIL does, C# *could* have had the ctor with an argument. `new int(whatever)` could just be sugar for `whatever` (type checked to be an int) - that's pointless, but possible.

Comment: @KendallFrey ints certainly do have constructors! An implicit default one - see the spec; http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/11.1.1.htm

Answer (score 5):

It's unnecessary - I much prefer:

```
int x = 12;
```

to

```
int x = new int(12);
```

The parameterless constructor is provided since `int` is a `struct`, I've never seen any production code that actually uses it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not required by the [spec](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/18.3.8.htm)

> A struct **can** declare instance constructors having parameters.

It's *not* **must**; therefore the provision of a constructor that takes parameters is entirely optional. The designers chose not to, so more power to them ;-)

**What other reasons could there be?**

**Simplification of Design?**

Lets imagine, for a second, that the framework designers had decided to provide a constructor:

```
int myInt = new int(99999999999999999999999999999999999);
```

The constructor's complexity has now increased. To avoid an overflow error, the bounds of the supplied value need to be checked.

So simplification is also an argument against providing a constructor.

The spec also defines the default value of "[simple-types](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/11.1.htm#simple-type)". For int, [it's 0](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/11.1.1.htm). It's possible that, as @KendallFrey mentions, there are optimizations for the instantiation of ints, however, they certainly **do** have a constructor - an implicit default one that initializes the value to 0. IIRC (and I'll see if I can dig it out later), simple types are actually instantiated by the memory manager. Additional constructor logic here might also complicate the issue.

**Enforce Semantics?**

As @rich.okelly mentions, int x = 12; just looks right; the reason for this is because we often understand value type semantics to include directly assigning the value. For me, the reference type assignment var x = new RefType(); has always inferred that there is a different process happening for allocation and assignment; novice users might expect that:

```
int x = new int(12);
```

and

```
XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
```

to be in some way equivalent.

Note:

I don't really believe this is a question that can be answered by anyone other than whomever implemented this in the Framework.